# C++: Overloading the << operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, priority-queue, ostream

I have a very silly problem that I just can't figure out. I'm trying to overload the << operator in my "PrioQueue" class. I'm still pretty new to C++ and i've tried almost every example I could find on the web but nothing works.

The PrioQueue is a template class I made that works like a normal Queue but puts the highest value it receives on the top.

```
PrioQueue<int> intq1(5);
intq1.push(1);
intq1.push(2);
intq1.push(1);
cout << intq1;
```

The << operator should write all the values that I've pushed to the queue with a '|' in between. So like this:

2 | 1 | 1 |

This is my overload operator << method.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, PrioQueue q){
    while(!q.empty()){
        out.write(q.pop()); //This method pops off the top value and returns it
    }
    return out;
```

}

I hope this is enough information but if not. This is my full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Type>
class PrioQueue
{
private:
Type *bottom_;
Type *top_;
int size_;
public:
PrioQueue(Type size){
    bottom_ = new Type[size];
    top_ = bottom_;
    size_ = size;
}

friend PrioQueue operator+(PrioQueue q1, PrioQueue q2){
    while(!q2.empty()){
        q1.push(q2.pop());
    }
    return q1;
}

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, PrioQueue q){
    while(!q.empty()){
        out.write(q.pop());
    }
    return out;
}


//Checks to see if the given value is bigger than the bottom character. 
//If so, the bottom and the given value swap places. 
//If not, the value gets placed at the top of the queue
void push(Type t){
    if(*bottom_ < t){
        *top_ = *bottom_;
        *bottom_ = t;
    }else{
        *top_ = t;
    }
    top_++;
}

int num_items() {
    return (top_ - bottom_);
}

Type pop(){
    return *(bottom_++);
}

int full() {
    return (num_items() >= size_);
}

int empty() {
    return (num_items() <= 0);
}

void print(){
    cout << "Queue currently holds " << num_items() << " items: " ;
    for (Type *element=top_-1; element >= bottom_; element--) {
        cout << " " << *element;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int getSize(){
    return size_;
}

~PrioQueue(){ // stacks when exiting functions
    bottom_ = 0;
    delete[] bottom_;
}
};

void intExample(){
PrioQueue<int> intq1(5);
intq1.push(1);
intq1.push(2);
intq1.push(1);
cout << intq1;

intq1.print();

PrioQueue<int> intq2(5);
intq2.push(8);
intq2.push(2);
intq2.push(5);
intq2.print();

PrioQueue<int> intq3(10);
intq3 = intq1 + intq2;
intq3.print();

cout << intq3;
}

void charExample(){
PrioQueue<char> charq1(5);
charq1.push('t');
charq1.push('h');
charq1.push('g');
charq1.print();

PrioQueue<char> charq2(5);
charq2.push('i');
charq2.push('q');
charq2.push('k');
charq2.print();

PrioQueue<char> charq3(10);
charq3 = charq1 + charq2;
charq3.print();
}

int main(){
intExample();
charExample();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, you might want to rethink the design of removing all of the contents when doing output (same thing is true of your `+` operator).

Comment: @crashmstr I was just typing a comment about that. It is not a problem since the object is being passed in by value. However, you may want to provide an explicit copy constructor just to be sure that the copy you are passing in doesn't secretly share some data structure with the original.

Comment: @CompuChip true, but in my mind it makes more sense to pass a `const &` and then iterate in a non-destructive way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, PrioQueue q){
  while(!q.empty()){
    out << q.pop() << "|";
  }
  return out << "\n"; // if you want a newline, otherwise just "return out;"
}
```

**Edit** Note that for this to work, you will have to modify your queue to be copyable. You need to add a copy constructor and an assignment operator (see [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)) or use a type that is copyable and assignable to store your data (see `std::vector`, `std::deque`, or container adapter `std::priority_queue` if this is not an exercise).

Comment: That would be fine, if the queue were (correctly) copyable. Although, being a friend, it might make more sense access the data directly without the need to copy it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks. I had incorrectly assumed that the queue is copyable, and the copy is intentional, since printing a queue should probably not empty it. But now I see there are problems. I added something about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `out.write()` expects a `const char*` and `size`. First of all, your `Type` will not implicitly convert to c`onst char*` and also, you're missing an argument.

Using out << `q.pop()` will fix the problem for you.